# How do I display posts with specific value in a custom field into my loop?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop

I'm trying to display posts that contains a specific value from my custom field.
For example, I created a custom field that asks for the year, let's say I would like to display only posts with the year 2013 in the custom field, how would I do this?

this is what I have so far:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Sport', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

I tried something like this:

```
     <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Sport', array('meta_key' => 'year_comm', 'meta_value' =>'2013'), 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ); ?>
```

but it does not work, I just get all the posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) argument of `WP_Query`. For example, if your custom field name is "year" and you want to get the post with `year=2013`:

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'      => 'Sport',
                                 'posts_per_page' => 3,
                                 'meta_query'     => array( 'meta_key'   => 'year_comm',
                                                            'meta_value' => '2013',
                                                            //Assuming you are using numeric value
                                                            //if not, delete the next line
                                                            'type'       => 'NUMERIC'
    ) ) );
?>
```

Or use the custom field parameters:

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'      => 'Sport',
                                 'posts_per_page' => 3,
                                 'meta_key'       => 'year_comm'
                                 //Assuming you are using numeric value
                                 //if not, use meta_value
                                 'meta_value_num' => '2013'
    ) );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! First one doesn't work for some reason, but the second one works great.